WhereFilter in Weaviate Not Working When Deleting Records Using Java Client
I am trying to delete a Weaviate object using WhereFilter in Java, but it is not deleting the object.
Below is the code for deleting the object:
client.batch()
    .objectsBatchDeleter()
    .withClassName(objectClass)
    .withWhere(WhereFilter.builder()
        .path("_metadata", "id")
        .operator(Operator.Equal)
        .valueString("1")
        .build())
    .run();

The following screenshot shows the Weaviate object that I am trying to delete:

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
I believe the issue is with the .path() method. I have tried the following ways, but none of these seem to be working:

path("_metadata.id")
path("/_metadata/id")
path("_metadata").path("id")
path("_metadata", "id")


Duda from Weaviate here
a proper syntax for reaching into reference properties is:
.path("<CROSS_REFERENCE_NAME>", "<REF_CLASS_NAME>", "<PROPERTY_OF_REF_CLASS>")

In your case:
.path("_metadata", "<REF_CLASS_NAME>", "id")

This was also answered here:
Thanks!
